# how to avoid repeated compilation of packages in extra-deps

Tags: haskell-stack

I have a project consisting of several packages in a directory tree. If I change one of the packages then stack does usually automatically recompiles packages which depend on the changed one (sometimes   the automatism fails and i have no hint when - but this is not the focus of the question).

during the recompilation, i see often a recompilation of all the packages listed as extra-deps. these have not changed and recompilation is unnecessary (but time consuming).  I understand that there is some mechanism to compile such dependencies only once (as long as they are not changing) and to be reused. i saw once a message from stack saying that some previous compilation of a package was reused pointing to this caching.

i was asked in a comment to provide the stack.yaml in the project directory (I tried also with entries like

```
- location: /home/frank/Workspace8/repo8/litMain
  extra-dep: true
```

but did not see a difference):

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- litMain      
- rdf4store    
- rdfhextension    
- uniform/uniform-strings    
- uniform/uniform-error     
- uniform/uniform-algebras      
- uniform/uniform-convenience       
- uniform/uniform-fileio       
- uniform/uniform-time       
extra-deps:
- chatter-0.8.0.1
- data-easy-0.7.0
- fullstop-0.1.4
- hgal-2.0.0.2
- non-negative-0.1.1
- numeric-prelude-0.4.2
- rdf4h-3.0.1
- test-invariant-0.4.5.0
- tokenize-0.3.0
resolver: lts-8.2
```

How to achieve the reuse of previously compiled and not changed extra-deps  in general?

I tried build, build --dependencies-only and build --snapshot but did not succeed. All the dependencies are rebuilt... i could not find more information in the documentation.

Helpful comments made me rethink and edit the question. I hope the problem is now better exposed. Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you have multiple packages in a single project or do you have multiple projects (and multiple `stack.yaml`s)?

Comment: Maybe show us the outline of your `stack.yaml`(s)?!

Comment: the stack.yaml is edited into the question. i also found information which is perhaps pertinent, but i cannot see how to use in https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/09/stack-more-binary-package-sharing

Comment: I still find it difficult to follow the description of your problem. Your sentence "If i change one of the projects then stack does not automatically update the other project which depend on this one." indicates that there are multiple projects but you really have only one? Maybe you could [open an issue for stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/new) and include all the steps necessary to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that a change in a local package shouldn't cause recompilation of any extra-deps as long as the extra-deps don't depend on any local packages. (Local packages are those that are listed in the `extra-deps` section.)

Usually my extra-deps are only recompiled when I upgrade stack or change the `resolver`.

This indicates that there might be a bug in stack's behavior, so it would be great if you could make a bug report for stack the next time you see this redundant recompilation again!